# Manipulate Client Machine From Web Application - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, auto-update

My company has several desktop applications that needs to be launched from an ASP.Net Core web application. Also the applications are going to be updated if there is a newer version. The web application would be working offline (only accessible to a specific LAN), and all the applications and clients would be in the same network. So basically, I am trying to create a **Launcher/Updater Web Application**.

The problem here is, web browsers are not capable manipulating (installing, launching or updating) applications that are on the client machine in a direct manner. We already checked Microsoft`s ClickOnce solution on updating applications but there are some reasons why we do not want to use it.

My question is, if there is any way to read, write and edit client side data, with or without an extra client side application from a Web application?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. There is no way to update client without using an additional program (at least in my experience). You won't be able to delete and replace libs and executable when the files are in use (read the software is running).

I wrote a small application to handle restart, update, and monitoring of the main application.

If you need more info about the approach I used let me know.

Comment: So if I understood it correctly, you wrote another application to update restart and monitor your applications, but you have also used a web application to launch your applications. My question is how did you run your applications or your updater application from web ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did. You are able to trigger restart, standby, update, computer restart, etc. directly from web page admin panel.

The web application must be connected to the second application via WebSocket so the data can be transferred between them. 

When we trigger a restart, for example, we send a command to the second application installed on the client. Then the second application handles restart, update, ... of the main application.

Comment: Okay can you please expand the WebSocket part of your solution. Because that is the part which I am exactly interested in. Ill accept your answer if you provide references and maybe a small portion of code showing the basics of WebSocket technology.

Comment: I used SignalR to implement this. There are a bunch of examples how to implement SignalR in .Net.